# 'All X' vs 'All the X'

Tags: difference, ellipsis

I alredy read [“All X” vs. “all of X” vs. “all the X”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80759/50720),  [“All rooms” versus “all the rooms”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/36379/50720),  and [Difference between 'all' and 'all the'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/80696/50720), but I still don't understand what are the similarities and differences in more complex syntax? Please elucidate and elaborate?

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+reasons+why%2Call+the+reasons+why&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20reasons%20why%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20the%20reasons%20why%3B%2Cc00) shows that **all the reasons why** dominates over [**all reasons why**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22all+reasons+why%22&safe=off&biw=1024&bih=615&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1700%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1999&tbm=bks#q=%22all+reasons+why%22&safe=off&tbas=0&tbm=bks&start=90). Yet on [p 165, *Postwestern Cultures: Literature, Theory, Space*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-xY3F8YCtF4C&pg=PA165&dq=%22all+reasons+why%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IdG1VJf7GI2PyATTtoGIBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22all%20reasons%20why%22&f=false), [English Prof Susan Kollin, PhD](http://www.montana.edu/english/faculty/kollin-susan.html) uses **all reasons wh**y:

> **All reasons why** queer public space—like a truly visible, thriving
>   center—starts to matter deeply.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular example, the explanation is that [ellipsis](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) (the acceptable leaving out of some predictable grammatical elements) is at work.

Here is what we can't see, but what most experienced/native speakers know is there:

We assume that several facts (let's call them Facts A, B, C, & D) have been given. Then,

> [These are] all reasons why queer public space matters.

It means A, B, C, & D each serve as reasons. It's possible that there are others.

If we use *These are all [of] the reasons,* we mean that there are no additional reasons.